# A Conformal Mapping problem

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

Can you give me a proof of this? I know it may use comformal mapping theorem but don't know how to do. Thanks you very much for your help!

Comment: One approach: Write out the Jacobian of the function $f(z) = f(x,y) = (u(x,y), v(x,y))$, and compare it to $|f'(z)|^2$, and then use the change of variables formula from multivariate calc.

Comment: I have done it, thank you!